# Insertion in a linked list having head as null

Tags: java, nodes, singly-linked-list

I have node class as

```
class Node{
  int data;
  Node next;
}
```

I have to insert nodes to the list.
It works properly. But always the head value is zero.

```
public void createlist(Node n,int p)
{  
    Node newone = new Node();
    newone.data=p;
    newone.next=null;
    if(n==null)
      n=newone;
    else
    {
        while(temp.next!=null)
         temp=temp.next;
        temp.next=newone;
    }
}
```

In main function I have created head node as

```
 public static void main(String args[] ) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node head=new Node();
    createlist(head,5);
 }
```

after creating this implementation the list starting from head looks like 
 0->5. Why did the 0 come?.

Comment: *"It works properly."* it doesn't even compile - `temp` is not defined. Also you can't call a non-`static` method without an instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero comes from the `head` node itself:

```
Node head=new Node();
```

It is never modified by `createList` method, so the default value of zero remains in the `data` field.

It boils down to inability to change `head` inside `main` by assigning `n` in the code below:

```
if(n==null)
    n=newone;
```

That is why you are forced to create `new Node` inside `main`, so in fact `n` is 
never `null`.

You can fix this problem in several ways:

- **Treat the head node in a special way** - ignore the `head` node in for printing, deletions, etc., or
- **Change methods that operate on `Node` objects to return the modified list** - this would let you insert new nodes or delete the head node, or
- **Introduce a `MyList` class that owns all nodes** - move all list operations on the "umbrella" class, and deal with the `head` node there.

Comment: if head==null means , the head points to the newnode.So the head is modified as newnode . So how the previous 0 came?

Comment: @SaravananKS `head` is never `null`, because of the way that you call `createlist`. You allocate `head` inside `main`, that's the node that has zero in it.